# Why are these costants no longer valid after moving declarations to header file?

Tags: c++, mfc, header-files

I am writing a Tic-Tac-Toe program to practice MFC coding.

The screenshot below shows excerpts from the `.h` and `.cpp` files for the MFC dialog window (`CTTTDialog`) that will host the game.

This code will build successfully if I declare the two constants `GRIDROWS` and `GRIDCOLUMNS` within the event handler shown in the `.cpp` window (currently commented out at lines 152 and 153).

However, if I move the declarations to a public section of the header file (seen in line 51 and 52), several errors are flagged, including:

> E2435 'this' cannot be used in a constant expression

> C2131 expression did not evaluate to a constant

> failure was caused by a read of a variable outside its lifetime

What has gone wrong? If they are declared in the dialog's header, they ought to be "in scope" for any code that is part of that dialog, no?

Is there some other, more correct, way to declare the constants in the header?

(Why do I want to move them if they work OK in the event handler? Because I foresee that I will need these values to be available in a greater scope than just this one event handler)

[image: VS code windows]

Other non-constant values have been relocated to the header by me previously, and they have been fine... so far.

Comment: Please do not show excerpts of your code in images. Instead write up a [mre] demonstrating your issue with a full program and copy-paste this program as text into the question. See [ask].

Comment: *"to a public section of the header file"* -- Header files do not have public sections. Perhaps you meant a public section of a class definition?

Comment: *"lines 152 and 153"* -- That is a lot of lines for a [mre]. It's a good idea to eliminate the unnecessary so that they do not become distractions. In this case, the problem appears to center around a constant and an array. so you might to start with a constant (inside a class definition?) and an array definition, then add just enough code to reproduce the error. For example, try starting with `struct CTTTDialog { const int ROWS{3}; void foo(); }; void CTTTDialog::foo() { string gameRows[ROWS]; /* Do stuff */ }`

Answer (score 2):

A fixed-sized array is required to have its size known at compile time.

When your `const` variables are declared inside the handler, they are true **compile-time constants**, so they can be used in fixed-array declarations.

However, when you move the variables *as-is* into the class declaration, they are not longer *compile-time constants*, they become **instance (non-static) variables** instead. Reading them is dependent on the class object's `this` pointer at runtime.  Thus, they cannot be used to declare fixed-arrays at compile-time, only to allocate dynamic arrays at runtime (`new[]`, `std::vector`, etc).

To do what you are attempting, you need to declare the class variables as either `inline static const` or as `static constexpr` to make them be *compile-time constants* again, eg:

```
inline static const int GRIDROWS{ 3 };
inline static const int GRIDCOLUMNS{ 3 };
```

```
static constexpr int GRIDROWS{ 3 };
static constexpr int GRIDCOLUMNS{ 3 };
```